# Link num type variable with aio Staubli

Tags: ros, robotic-arm, control, robot

I want to link a num variable with a aio input variable I receive from ECAT.
[image]

I am trying to do it in that way, but it does not work. Anyone who know how to do it in SRS?

I have defined Vel_cmd and Vel variables as:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The aioGet is the correct way to read the current value of an analog input, but it is not a link. When the aio variable Vel[0] changes Vel_cmd[0] do not automatically update. You will need to run the aioGet instruction again to get the new value.

You can create a new task running the aioGet instructions in a loop. set a delay of about 4 milliseconds inside the loop to reduce CPU loading.

[image]